# Unable to Add Event to Dynamically Generated Control using {}

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been investigating methods of adding controls to another parent control in C#,
I'm aware that there are an array of methods to accomplish this, and the simple thing to do would be to follow those - however, I'm curious about the inability to do so using the method below:

**Method A**

```
Container.Controls.Add(new Button //Add the control straight to the parent
{
    Name = "Button Name",
    Text = "Button Text",
    Size = new Size(69, 69),
    Location = new Point(420, 420)
}.Click += DesignerButton_OnClick); //This is the only method Intellisense recognised, even though it does not work...
```

In comparison to a method that does work:

**Method B**

```
Button NewButton = new Button();
NewButton.Name = "Button Name";
NewButton.Text = "Button Text";
NewButton.Size = new Size(69, 69);
NewButton.Location = new Point(420, 420);
NewButton.Click += DesignerButton_OnClick; //Add the handler
Container.Controls.Add(NewButton); //Add control to parent
```

I highly doubt it is an issue with the function I'm calling, however for the sake of problem solving here it is - plain and simple:

**Handling Function**

```
private static void DesignerButton_OnClick(object Sender, EventArgs Ev)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

**The Question**

Is there a way to add an event handler to the button generated through *Method A*?

Comment: No there isn't.  Method A is for setting fields & properties only.

Comment: Well I guess that answers my last few months of occasionally wondering but being lazy and using Method B. I doubt there'd be much reason to use Method A anyway, just looks to be a way of saving time (barely) - I don't see much of a performance benefit either, slightly easier on the eyes though for maintenance.

Comment: It's useful to elaborate on why something doesn't work.  I'm guessing you mean "doesn't compile".  Your code is basically equivalent to Container.Controls.Add(btn.Click += handler).  You aren't adding the button to the collection, you are adding whatever the result of an event+= operation returns (which, it seems, is "void").  Not everything uses a fluent interface

Comment: Another line: `Container.Controls.Last().Click += DesignerButton_OnClick;` or `Container.Controls.First(control => control.Name == "Button Name").Click += DesignerButton_OnClick;`

Comment: Or you can create an extension method for `static Control AddAndReturn(this ControlCollection controls, Control control) { controls.Add(control); return control; }`

Comment: There is an ask in the [C# language repo](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/307) to add event subscriptions to object initializers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
new Button
{
    Parent = Container, // the same as Container.Controls.Add
    Name = "Button Name",
    Text = "Button Text",
    Size = new Size(69, 69),
    Location = new Point(420, 420)
}.Click += DesignerButton_OnClick;
```

Or if you need local variable:

```
var NewButton = new Button
{
    Parent = Container,
    Name = "Button Name",
    Text = "Button Text",
    Size = new Size(69, 69),
    Location = new Point(420, 420)
};
NewButton.Click += DesignerButton_OnClick;
```

Comment: Very nice method, probably the most simple out of all of them and does the job with optimal code.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it with a handy extension method:

```
public static class Ex
{
    public static T Attach<T>(this T sender, Action<T> addHandler)
    {
        addHandler(sender);
        return sender;
    }
}
```

Then you can write your code like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var btn = new Button()
    {
        Name = "Button Name",
        Text = "Button Text",
        Size = new Size(69, 69),
        Location = new Point(420, 420)
    }.Attach(b => b.Click += DesignerButton_OnClick);

    btn.PerformClick();
}

private static void DesignerButton_OnClick(object Sender, EventArgs Ev)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Clicked!");
}
```

That when I run it writes out `Clicked!` to the console.

You can chain the `Attach` calls to wire up more than one event.

Now you can easily wrap that in a `Container.Controls.Add(...)` call.

Comment: I like this method a lot, however, for my implementation, I was looking for something simple like @Alexander Petrov answer.

Comment: @Hex - Sure, no problem. Just keep in mind that this approach allows you to attach as many handlers as you need - and for that matter, run any code against the button, before adding to the parent collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method to return the added control:

```cs
// Case A
public static Control AddAndReturn(this ControlCollection controls, Control control)
{
    controls.Add(control);
    return control;
}

// Case B
public static Control Add(this ControlCollection controls, Control control, bool returnControl)
{
    controls.Add(control);
    if (returnControl)
        return control;
    return null;
}
```

And you can use it as you want:

```cs
// Case A
Container.Controls.AddAndReturn(new Button
{
    Name = "Button Name",
    Text = "Button Text",
    Size = new Size(69, 69),
    Location = new Point(420, 420)
}).Click += DesignerButton_OnClick;

// Case B
Container.Controls.Add(new Button
{
    Name = "Button Name",
    Text = "Button Text",
    Size = new Size(69, 69),
    Location = new Point(420, 420)
}, returnControl: true).Click += DesignerButton_OnClick;
```